# [Java][Android] Implicit intent and createchooser combination

Tags: java, android, android-intent, geolocation, android-intent-chooser

I think my problem is solved super easy. I have 2 possible intents and both use their Default category to get seen by chooser, but if i want to put extra the chooser won't even start!

Both have in manifest.xml

```
  1  <activity
  2   android:name=".OneActivity"
  3   android:label="OA">
  4              <intent-filter>
  5                  <action android:name="specialpackage.package.LOCALIZE"/>
  6                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  7              </intent-filter>
  8  </activity>
```

and inside the Activity:

```
      1     Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(new Intent("specialpackage.package.LOCALIZE"), "App auswählen:");
      2     intent.putExtra("someNotes", currentNote); //Is defined and not important
      3     intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("notes", notes);
      4      startActivity(intent);
                          (ArrayList<DBH.Note> notes = helper.getNotes(currentProject);)
```

If i comment out 2 and 3 it works and let me choose my apps. If i dont use the chooser and putExtra and ParcelableArrayListExtra on simpel intent with .OneActivity it works ._.

I'm allowed to only change in the manifest and this class ._. maybe startActivityOnResult somehow? Already tried and didn't work.

EDIT1:

```
 1      Intent testintent = new Intent("specialpackage.package.LOCALIZE");
 2      testintent.putExtra("current note", currentNote);
 3      testintent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("notes", notes);
 4      Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(testintent, "App auswählen:");  
 5      startActivity(intent);
```

Not working, too :D As i said without putExtra it works, but if i use putExtra in Debugger it puts the Extra on the intent but on startActivity it says android is closing repeatedly (sry bad english im german xD)

Comment: "If i comment out 2 and 3 it works and let me choose my apps" -- put the extras on the `new Intent("specialpackage.package.LOCALIZE")` `Intent`, not the `Intent` returned by `createChooser()`.

Comment: Already tried this :D will post it again wait a mom